# Firefox version supported by selenium webdriver 2.25.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, firefox, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I restarted working on an older rails project today. One problem driving me crazy is that I can't get my javascript test cases to run, although I remember them all passing when I left the project. I am using

selenium-webdriver 2.25.0
capybara 1.1.2
cucumber 1.2.1

but firefox doesn't start when I run the tests. All I get is

> unable to start Firefox cleanly, args: ["-silent"] 
>   (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

I guess this is because of updating firefox and I tried to install several older versions but none of them works. Which version is supported by selenium-webdriver 2.25.0?

Comment: Well what version of Firefox do you have?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is annoying. I just upgrade the driver and it usually does the trick:

```
bundle update selenium-webdriver
```

Answer (score 5):

Selenium Webdriver 2.25 [supports Firefox up to version 17](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG)